# Alternate for SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION

Tags: android

SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION deprecated in Android API level 28. What is the alternates for get all these states?

```
ASSOCIATED 
ASSOCIATING
AUTHENTICATING
COMPLETED
DISCONNECTED
```

Comment: SupplicantState.ASSOCIATED 
                    SupplicantState.ASSOCIATING 
                    SupplicantState.AUTHENTICATING 
                    SupplicantState.COMPLETED 
                    SupplicantState.DISCONNECTED

Comment: Did u find any alternative for this?